# Send image as document to whatsapp programmatically

Tags: java, android, send, whatsapp

The question is, how do I send a large image (example 720 * 8549) to the WhatsApp without compression and loss of quality.
Is it possible to do this?

Below is the code to send the image that I use:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
File photoFile = new File(imageFile.getParent(), imageFile.getName());
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 
photoFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,photoURI);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getBaseContext().getString(R.string.photo_share)));
```

So I send a compressed and unreadable image.
Maybe someone came across a similar.

Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because WhatsApp always reduces the size. Google Photos also tried this but if you choose *Original* when sending over Google Photos the size is still shrinked in the end.

Why do you not take another app like Telegram? You have much more options there.
The easiest way would be to share a link to the original e.g. Google Photos or Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I have an app (for example, a gallery) in which I want to implement the transfer of images, including long ones, to social applications without going into them.